# If ${x_n}$ strictly decreasing and $\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_n=0$ then does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n-x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis

Let ${x_n}$ be a strictly decreasing sequence with $\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_n=0$.
Is true that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n-x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ diverges?

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`.

Comment: Veri nice, DR.X, but I can't see the code... :) Nevertheless, I have found it googling.

Comment: $link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. $

Comment: When you press add a comment there is a little section with formatting info bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general theory of [infinite products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) says that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q_n)$ (with $0\le q_n\lt1$) converges to a nonzero number if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty q_n$ converges.  Now let $q_n=(x_n-x_{n+1})/x_n$, which satisfies the conditions $0\le q_n\lt1$.  Then

$$x_{n+1}=(1-q_n)x_n=(1-q_n)(1-q_{n-1})x_{n-1}=\cdots=\prod_{k=1}^n(1-q_k)x_1\to x_1\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-q_k)$$

The assumption $x_n\to0$ means the infinite product tends to $0$, so the infinite sum diverges.

Comment: To the proposer. Another useful theorem is that if $a_n\geq 0$ then $\sum_na_n$ converges iff $\prod_n(1+a_n)$ converges. ( Example: $a_n=1/n.$)This, and the theorem quoted in the A, are elementary.........+1

Answer (score 0):

Example:

$x_n=1/n$, decreasing , converges to $0$.

$x_n -x_{n+1} = 1/n -1/(n+1) = \dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$.

$a_n:= \dfrac{x_n-x_{n+1}}{x_n} =\dfrac{n}{n(n+1)} =$

$\dfrac {1}{n+1}.$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ diverges , harmonic series .

Comment: An even easier example would be $x_n=1/2^n$, which gives $a_n=1/2$ for all $n$.

Comment: Barry, definitely easier to prove that the sum of  your  a_n diverges .:))